# Bash shell to connect to a DB and run a query from in PSQL gives an unknown user:

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, psql

Im trying run from a shell a command without actually switching users or logging into the DB manually (so the shell doesnt get interrupted asking for the password)

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" WITH SCHEMA public;
```

Is what Im looking fordward to run in the Database called ticketing  with user ticketng

I already have my .pgpass file setup and working aswell as my psql DB user ticketing created

```
sudo -H -u postgres bash -c "cd && psql -c \"CREATE ROLE ticketing LOGIN CREATEDB;\""
sudo -H -u postgres bash -c "cd && psql -c \"ALTER USER ticketing WITH PASSWORD 'testpass';\""
sudo -H -u postgres bash -c "cd && psql -c \"CREATE DATABASE ticketing WITH ENCODING='UTF8' OWNER=ticketing CONNECTION LIMIT=-1;\""
sudo -H -u postgres bash -c "cd && psql -c \"ALTER USER ticketing WITH SUPERUSER;\""
```

Up to here everything is fine and yet when try to conect to the ticketing DB into a single line to automate this, it simply doesnt work, after running

```
sudo -H -u ticketing bash -c "cd && psql -c \"CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" WITH SCHEMA public;\""
```

I get a:

**sudo: unknown user: ticketing**

**sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin**

What I am trying to achieve can be done by running manually the following lines

```
psql -h localhost -U ticketing
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" WITH SCHEMA public;
\q
```

however this stops the shell form actually beung "automatic"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the backslash hell! You need to prepend three backslashes to the double-quote surrounding `uuid-ossp` to get the right output:

```shell
sudo -H -u ticketing bash -c "cd && psql -c \"CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \\\"uuid-ossp\\\" WITH SCHEMA public;\""
```

Because:

```shell
bash-3.2$ echo "cd && psql -c \"CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \\\"uuid-ossp\\\" WITH SCHEMA public;\""

cd && psql -c "CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"uuid-ossp\" WITH SCHEMA public;"
```

Comment: Thanks  i just added the slashes, and sorry i had to edit the question since i wasnt clear on the problem, the backlashes seem to be ANOTHER Problem i might have, but right now my problem is that my query is not acknowledging the user ticketing, even when i can connect to it manually

Comment: Do you have a Linux user called "ticketing"? Check `/etc/passwd` (don't paste it).

Comment: no i dont just checked, i just have my user and postgres

Comment: The command `sudo` switched Linux/System user but not PostgreSQL users. However if you want to access `psql` by using the system user "ticketing", you need firstly create it: `sudo adduser ticketing` and follow the steps.

Comment: ticketing was created as a role in postgres using ```sudo -H -u postgres bash -c "cd && psql -c \"CREATE ROLE ticketing LOGIN CREATEDB;\""```

Comment: @GoatAdmin Most PostgreSQL release has a default `pg_hba.conf` file which allows direct access from "sameuser" using no password.

Comment: Thanks I actually got it working by reading all of your advice

Answer (score 0):

You're in a bit of quoting hell. The innermost quotes are unescaped and will disappear. Throw some single quotes into the mix:

```
sudo -H -u ticketing bash -c "cd && psql -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS \"uuid-ossp\" WITH SCHEMA public;'"
# ...........................1..............2...............................3...........3....................21
```

or use a heredoc which is very tidy:

```
sudo -H -u ticketing bash <<__END__
cd && psql -c 'CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp" WITH SCHEMA public;'
__END__
```

Comment: thanks and sorry i have edited my question, this might be another problem i have tho and its useful